# Cloning git repository permission denied

Tags: git, bitbucket

i have a private repository on my bitbucket account. Today i wanted
to add a new computer to get access to one of the private repositories.

So i did the following:

```
ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/d/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/d/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /d/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /d/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

After that i copied the key from id_rsa.pub and added it to my list of
ssh-keys on my bitbucket repository.

However... when i now want to clone my repository i get the following error:

```
Permssion denied (publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying to access the repository as the user who created the keys?

Comment: yes i am sure about that

Comment: @ÖzgürEroğlu to access BitBucket via SSH, the user is always `git`, so the local user as which @user1882812 is accessing the repository doesn't matter

Comment: @LoicAG No it is not. Keypairs are generated at users computer. Only that user who created the pair have access to the private one locally. Otherwise any user who have user accounts on my server would be able to see my repos. Check out the content of your public key. User at bitbucket side is git as you said.

Comment: @ÖzgürEroğlu I get your point now, I guess "access the repository as the user..." mislead me: I thought you meant the SSH user; you meant the local user, is that correct?

Comment: @ÖzgürEroğlu and for the sake of completeness, I'll point out that inspecting the public key may give a hint as to who created the key, but is not a reliable way to determine its actual owner (in the UNIX sense)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the generated private key (`id_rsa` in your case) when cloning from BitBucket:

```
git -i /path/to/your/private/key clone git@bitbucket.org/owner/project.git
```

**Edit**
A more permanent and convenient solution would be to omit the `-i /path/to/your/private/key` part in the above command, and instead include the following in your SSH configuration file:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  IdentityFile /path/to/your/private/key
```